# Calculate the number of ways for random walk

Tags: probability, combinatorics, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Suppose there are $N$ nodes. A man starts at node 1. When he is at node $i$, he can either move forwards to $i+1$ or backwards to $i-1$. He get to node N at step T. The question is how many ways are there?

My thinkings:
If $T=N$, obviously there are only one way to get to N.
If $T=N+2k+1$, the problem is infeasible;
But how to calculate if $T=N+2k$?

Besides, I think this is a very classical problem, could any give the name of this problem?

Comment: I think your problem is *random walk*. But the wiki pages are involving the general case which is not necessary to solve your problem. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) may give you some inspiration.

Comment: Try making a recurrence relation.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo Could you please give more hints since I faild to make the recurrence.

Comment: @virtualize, How can this related to Pascal's triangle?

Comment: Note that if $T\lt N$ then $n=0$. If $T=N$, then $n=1$ as you said. And if $T=N+2k$, then you have $(N-2)^k$ possible places where you can go back and forth once.